# $A$ open relative to $Y \subset X$, where $X$ is a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to understand Rudin's proof of theorem 2.30, which states:

> Suppose $Y \subset X$. A subset $A$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ iff
>   there exists an open subset $A'$ of $X$ such that $A = A' \cap Y$

In particular, I have a question about the $\Rightarrow$ direction.

I will cite the relevant parts of the proof:

Suppose $A$ is open relative to $Y$. Then,

$$\forall a \in A: \exists \epsilon_a > 0: B_Y(a, \epsilon_a) \subset A$$

And then Rudin defines $A' = \bigcup_{a \in A} B_X(a, \epsilon_A)$

In particular, he proves that $A' \cap Y\subset A$ in the following way (and I understand all the steps):

Fix $a \in A$. If $x \in B_X(a, \epsilon_a)\cap Y $, then $x \in B_Y(a, \epsilon_a) \subset A$ hence, because $a \in A$ was arbitrary, it follows that $A' \cap Y \subset A$

However, I was wondering whether this approach works as well:

> Let $a \in A' \cap Y$. Then $a \in B_X(a, \epsilon_a)$ (because
>   $d(a,a) = 0$) and $a \in Y$, so $a \in B_Y(a, \epsilon_a) \subset
> \bigcup_{a \in A} B_Y(a, \epsilon_a) \subset A$

Comment: When you write "Then $a \in B_X(a,\epsilon_a)$", you assume what is to be proved, namely that $a\in A$.

Comment: Did I? $a \in B_X(a, \epsilon_a) \iff d(a,a) < \epsilon_a \land a \in X$ and this is true without using that $a \in A$?

Comment: Ah okay nevermind my last comment. I see what went wrong. Make your comment an answer and I'll gladly accept and upvote it!

Comment: $\epsilon_a$ was only defined for elements of $A$. The issue would be easier to see if you started with "Let $x\in A'\cap Y$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\epsilon_a$ is only defined for $a\in A$, writing "$a \in B_X(a,\epsilon_a)$" already requires $a\in A$. That would be easier to see if the point in $A'\cap Y$ were called differently, say $x$. Then "$x \in B_X(x,\epsilon_x)$" isn't as tempting.

Comment: One last thing: Is the following correct: Let $x \in A' \cap Y$. Then, there exists $a \in A$ such that $x \in B_X(a, \epsilon_a)$ and $x \in Y$, which implies that $x \in B_Y(a, \epsilon_a) \subset A$. Hence, $A' \cap Y \subset A$?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct.

Comment: The thing is that $B_Y(a,r) = B_X(a,r) \cap Y$. So $$Y \cap\bigcup_{a\in A} B_X(a,\epsilon_a) = \bigcup_{a\in A} \bigl(Y \cap B_X(a,\epsilon_a)\bigr) = \bigcup_{a\in A} B_Y(a,\epsilon_a).$$

Comment: I see. Very useful comment. Thanks for that